# Syntax error while creating a table using SQL in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have created the following tables using SQL for import into a MySQL 5.5.24 database.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
'custId'          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'custName'        NOT NULL  VARCHAR(80),
'custfirmName'    VARCHAR(80),
'custAddress'     NOT NULL VARCHAR(80),
'custAddress2'    VARCHAR(45),
'custCity'        NOT NULL VARCHAR(45),
'custState'       NOT NULL CHAR(2),
'custZip'         NOT NULL CHAR(10),
'custPhone'       NOT NULL VARCHAR(12),
'custEmail'       NOT NULL VARCHAR(45), 
'custWebsite'     VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY(custId)
);
```

I have two resources and they indicate that my syntax is correct but I get an error message on the customer table:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''custId' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'custName' NOT NULL VARCHAR(80), 'c' at line 2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `  INT  `may need a a number/length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backticks for column names:-

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
`custId`            INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`custName`          VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
`custfirmName`      VARCHAR(80),
`custAddress`       VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
`custAddress2`      VARCHAR(45),
`custCity`          VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`custState`         CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`custZip`           CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`custPhone`         VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
`custEmail`         VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,    
`custWebsite`       VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY(custId)
);
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. One last question, what is the key combination for a back tick?

Answer (score 1):

Try without quotes and putting `NOT NULL` at the end of each field declaration :

```
 CREATE TABLE customers
  (
     custid       INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
     custname     VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
     custfirmname VARCHAR(80),
     custaddress  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
     custaddress2 VARCHAR(45),
     custcity     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     custstate    CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
     custzip      CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     custphone    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
     custemail    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
     custwebsite  VARCHAR(45),
     PRIMARY KEY(custid)
  );
```

or using backticks (allows spaces in field name) :

```
 CREATE TABLE customers
  (
    `custid`       INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `custname`     VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `custfirmname` VARCHAR(80),
    `custaddress`  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `custaddress2` VARCHAR(45),
    `custcity`     VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `custstate`    CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `custzip`      CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `custphone`    VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    `custemail`    VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `custwebsite`  VARCHAR(45),
    PRIMARY KEY(custid)
  );
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f35ba6).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
`custId`            INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`custName`          VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
`custfirmName`      VARCHAR(80),
`custAddress`       VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
`custAddress2`      VARCHAR(45),
`custCity`          VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`custState`         CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`custZip`           CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`custPhone`         VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
`custEmail`         VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,    
`custWebsite`       VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY(custId)
);
```

The above tested with MySQL Workbench.